# argument of type * is incompatible with parameter of type *

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a project for my "Programming I" class, and I am getting a strange error.  It's a payroll program that calculates taxes and what-not, and our professor wants us to put some of our functions in separate `.cpp` files.

I've set it up so that each employee is treated as a struct:

```
#include <string>    
using namespace std;

struct Employee {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string name;
    double rate;
    double hours;
    char status;
    double grossPay;
    double insurance;
    double socialSecurity;
    double stateTax;
    double federalTax;
    double PYE;
    double netPay;
};
```

In my main program, I have an array of seven employees: "employees", and initialize it from a separate text file, but when I try to pass the array to one of my functions in the separate `.cpp` files, I get this error:

> argument of type "Employee *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Employee *"

The thing is, though that only happens on the first two out of three functions, while the third is fine even when commenting out the first two:

```
int main() {
    const int numEmployees = 7;
    Employee employees[numEmployees];

    cout << "name" << setw(20) << right << "rate" << setw(8) << "hours" << setw(7) << "ins" << setw(7) << "soc" << setw(7) << "state" << setw(7) << "fed" << setw(7) << "net" << endl
         << setw(46) << "sec" << setw(6) << "tax" << setw(8) << "tax" << endl;

    fstream data("employees.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++) {
        data >> employees[i].firstName >> employees[i].lastName >> employees[i].rate >> employees[i].hours >> employees[i].status;

        employees[i].name = employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName;
    }

    computeGrossPay(employees, numEmployees);   //<-\
    computeInsurance(employees, numEmployees);  //<- these two are errors
    computeFederalTax(employees, numEmployees); //<-- this one is fine

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++) {
        // compute social security withheld as 7%  of gross pay
        employees[i].socialSecurity = employees[i].grossPay * 0.07;

        // compute state tax as 3% of gross pay
        employees[i].stateTax = employees[i].grossPay * 0.03;

        // Compute PYE (Projected Yearly earnings) as gross-pay times 52.
        employees[i].PYE = employees[i].grossPay * 52;

        // Compute Net pay as gross-pay  minus  insurance  minus  soc-sec minus state-tax minus fed-tax
        employees[i].netPay = employees[i].grossPay - employees[i].insurance - employees[i].socialSecurity - employees[i].stateTax - employees[i].federalTax;
    }

    printPayroll(employees, numEmployees);
}
```

Here are what each of the functions look like, each in their own separate file:

```cpp
void computeGrossPay(Employee* employees, int numEmployees) {
    // do stuff
}
```

```cpp
void computeInsurance(Employee* employees, int numEmployees) {
    // do stuff
}
```

```cpp
void computeFederalTax(Employee* employees, int numEmployees) {
    // do stuff
}
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I believe this may have been a problem with my IDE. I was using Visual Studio, and as other users pointed out, it compiles just fine elsewhere. I think I'll stick to basic text editors until I'm ready for the more advanced IDEs.

Comment: The function expects a pointer and you are passing the object! pass a pointer to the object instead

Comment: Always look at the first error/warning message . The other messages might be cascades from the compiler guessing what you actually meant in the first error situation ; and it might stop giving further errors for the same thing after  certain number of times encountering that error.  A good practice is to fix the first error and recompile .

Comment: To improve the question, post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You've made a mistake somewhere with having the correct definition of `Employee` visible to the functions, but we can't be any more specific based on the little bits of code posted so far

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of passing `Employee*` and size around, consider using a `std::vector<Employee>`.

Comment: Do not tell, show. How exactly `employees` declared. How exactly function prototypes were declared.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/EhLRir

Comment: Even the full code doesn't reproduce it. Also tried without --std=c++17, and it still works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have several remarks about this code. This code is using C-style arrays, and passing it as pointers and pointer size, which is ill-advised. Also, It doesn't use some of the most basic concepts of C++.

I have made some rearrangements - mostly made Employee into a real struct/class, with its own member functions, instead of passing it from outside. Made the array using the std::array (which is preferable over the raw array), and finally, a small touch - made the number of employees a `constexpr`.

I haven't arranged the input parsing, but actually, Employee needs to be a **class**, that disallows touching the values of its members from outside, and should have a constructor, which gets all the relevant inputs, instead of what is done now.

Look at this rearranged code:

```
using namespace std; // I strongly suggest against it!!!!

struct Employee {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string name;
    double rate;
    double hours;
    char status;
    double grossPay;
    double insurance;
    double socialSecurity;
    double stateTax;
    double federalTax;
    double PYE;
    double netPay;

    void computeAll() // a bad name, but I don't have a better idea now!
    {
        computeGrossPay();
        computeInsurance();
        computeFederalTax();
        computeSocialSecurity();
        computeStateTax();
        computePYE();
        computeNetPay();
    }

private:
    void computeGrossPay();
    void computeInsurance();
    void computeFederalTax();
    void computeSocialSecurity();
    void computeStateTax();
    void computePYE();
    void computeNetPay();
};

int main() {
    constexpr uint64_t NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES = 7;
    std::array<Employee, NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES> employees{};

    cout << "name" << setw(20) << right << "rate" << setw(8) << "hours" << setw(7) << "ins" << setw(7) << "soc" << setw(7) << "state" << setw(7) << "fed" << setw(7) << "net" << endl
         << setw(46) << "sec" << setw(6) << "tax" << setw(8) << "tax" << endl;

    fstream data("employees.txt");

    for (auto& employee : employees) 
    {
        data >> employee.firstName >> employee.lastName >> employee.rate >> employee.hours >> employee.status;

        employee.name = employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName;

        employee.computeAll();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the reason you didn't try to answer OP:s question is because it's very hard to answer it until he provides a [mcve]?

Comment: As I have written in the beginning of my answer, the program compiles properly. However, I noticed that I can help him on the way with other things...

(Which on its own, solves the problem, since it no longer uses `Employee*` inside of the functions).

Comment: I also mentioned that I couldn't reproduce the error OP got and left a link to demo that it compiles just fine. I made that a comment since I wasn't able to answer the question either.

Comment: Why would you suggest against using the std namespace? Does it impact performance?

Comment: @ChrisHussey Namespaces are built in order to distinguish between different classes/functions (and so on) names. When you use `using namespace std;` you lose information about ***where*** this name comes from (for example, when using `cout` you cannot know it is from `std`). Also, it may cause name ambiguity, which in the good case will cause a compilation error, and in the bad, you will get the wrong function/class. Therefore, avoid it altogether!

Comment: @ChrisHussey It does not impact runtime performance if it compiles. Compile time performace - yes, slightly. What's worse is the ambiguity Kerek mentioned. There's really no good reason to ever bring `std` into the global namespace. Use it inside specific functions to bring in extra overloads but not as a generic solution to "I'm to tired to type".